Provide an overload signature for a mixin that returns class with protected and optional properties
I've got some mixin that returns an abstract class, with some method and properties and optional properties, like so
type AbstractConstructor<T = any> = abstract new (...args: any[]) => T

interface IMyMixin {
  someProp: PropType;
  optionalProp?: OptionalType;
  mustImplement(): void;
  availableMethod() void;;
}

type IMyMixinWithOptional = IMyMixin & {optionalProp: OptionalProp;}

export function MixItIn<T extends AbstractConstructor>(
  base:T ,
  withOptional: true
): AbstractConstructor<IMyMixinWithOptional>
export function MixItIn<T extends AbstractConstructor>(
  base: T,
  withOptional?: boolean
): AbstractConstructor<IMyMixin>
export function MixItIn<T extends AbstractConstructor>(
  base: T,
  withOptional?: boolean
) {
  abstract class MyMixin extends base implements IMyMixin {
    someProp = new PropType();
    optionalProp = withOptional ? new OptionalType() : undefined;

    abstract mustImplement(): void;

    availableMethod() {
      // does stuff
    }
  }
  return MyMixin;
}

export function MyConvenientMixin(withOptional: true): AbstractConstructor<IMyMixinWithOptional>
export function MyConvenientMixin(withOptional?: boolean): AbstractConstructor<IMyMixin>
export function MyConvenientMixin(withOptional?: boolean): AbstractConstructor<IMyMixin> {
  return MixItIn(class {}, withOptional)
}

here I would like the overload signatures to tell the client that they get the optional property for sure if they call either the mixin or the convenience method with true.
2 problems:

some properties of IMyMixin are actually protected. the extending class should be aware it has them and can use them, but they should be protected. I can't declare these properties as protected though in an interface. I tried to use an abstract class instead, but get errors that I am not implementing the abstract class correctly.

classes using the mixin like class MyClass extends MixItIn(SomeOtherClass) { } are unaware that they have methods belonging to SomeOtherClass


